# how to return a project's 'project key' programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script

I can easily get the project key by going to File --> Project Properties --> Project key (on the info tab)

but is there any way to return the 'project key' from the script itself?

Comment: Do add-ons have different/unique project keys or do they share main project's key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid Apps Script doesn't currently support this at the moment. Best practice now is to create a String constant in your script, copy the key into it, and reference the constant whenever you need the key.

However, this means that if you copy the script, you will need to update the constant in the copy (copied scripts have different keys than the original).

Comment: Do add-ons have different/unique project keys or do they share main project's key?

Comment: The project key is tied to the script, so anyone using an add-on will be using the same script with the same key.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
ScriptApp.getProjectKey()
```

to programmatically get the script's project key.

Comment: When I try this it doesn't seem to match the project key shown in File > Project Properties.